# Context returning null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-asynctask

I am writing an `AsyncTask` which includes a `progressDialog`. When I try to pass context as a parameter I get a null point exception. What is the proper parameter to pass? What `c` should be initialized to?

```
public class ExportDatabaseFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
Context c;
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(c.getApplicationContext());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

getApplicationContext() is usually overridden in most classes, try doing

```
private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
```

you can also pass a Context into the constructor of the Asynctask and then use that if you want.

Answer (score 1):

you dosen't initialized Context c.
pass the context to the constructor and initialize in the constructor the dialog.